# How to call a onclick print function and forget it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a print function and it opening a new tab window for print and then that print button keep active until I don't close that window by cancel or print. During that I am unable to call my other javascript function on parent page. So my question is , is it possible to open a print window and that print button become inactive again, and windows keep open to print? below is my function.

```
function g_print_div(in_div_id) {

    div_id = in_div_id || 'idprint';
    var divElements = document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML;
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

    var printWindow = window.open();
    printWindow.document.write('<html>');

    printWindow.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/static/css/print.css') %]' />");

    printWindow.document.write('<body >');
    printWindow.document.write(divElements);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.print();

    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.close();
}
```

Calling with `onclick='g_print_div();'` function, If there is any other method to accomplish this, then let me know.

Comment: document.write is NOT like building a string.

Answer (score 0):

I search a lot and found other solution for this, I opened the print in the same tab windows rather in other window or new tab. Below link was helpful in this
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Print-DIV-content-without-opening-new-popup-window-using-JavaScript.aspx